# A proof for $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^3}{4+t^4} \sin{\omega t} \, dt = \frac \pi 2 e^{-\omega}, (w>0)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Given: $\omega >0, k>0$

I have to prove / disprove the given identity, **using only two of these integral identities:**

1. $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos{\omega t}}{\omega^2 + k^2} \, d\omega = \frac \pi {2k} e^{-kt}$
2. $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\omega \sin{\omega t}}{\omega^2 + k^2} \, d\omega = \frac \pi 2 e^{-kt}$

I tried to relate to eqn(2), assuming $t^2=v$ which gives us the relation:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^3}{4+t^4} \sin{\omega t} \, dt = \frac 1 2\int_0^\infty \frac{v}{4+v^2} \sin{(\omega \sqrt v)} \, dv$$
Couldn't proceed further. (Removing square root from sine function gave me trouble)

**Edit:** As @TheSimpliFire commented, Wolfram Alpha contradicts the relation.
In that case, using only the the aforementioned two integrals, what would be the correct value of the integral?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, plugging in $\omega = 0$ gives a contradiction immediately. The left hand side evaluates to $0$, but the right evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Also the left hand side is an odd function of $\omega$, but the right hand side is an even function of $\omega$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Sorry I missed something. actually it's $w >0, k>0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You are right. That absolute value makes the statement contradictory. I removed that.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, with $\omega = 1$, the integral equates to $\frac{\pi\cos 1}{2 e}$ not $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-1}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+infinity+x%5E3(sin+x)%2F(4%2Bx%5E4)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks for pointing out! But I'm still curious to know what would be the value of that integral, and how that could be evaluated using those two identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By partial fraction decomposition and the residue theorem

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^3}{4+t^4}\sin(\omega t)\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|\omega|}\cos(\omega)\operatorname{Sign}(\omega)}.$$
Indeed, this result just follows from the evaluation of 
$$ 2\pi\operatorname{Re}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\zeta}\left(\frac{z^3 e^{i|\omega|}}{4+z^4}\right) $$
at $\zeta=i\pm 1$.

Comment: What happens when $\omega=0$?

Comment: @lcv: you are right, I forgot a crucial $\text{Sign}$ term. Now fixed.

Comment: When you use \operatorname{Res} instead of \text{Res}, then the correct amount spacing between $3$ and $\operatorname{Res}$ and between $\operatorname{Res}$ and $f(x)$ will appear in $3\operatorname{Res} f(x)$ without needing to be added manually, and will be context-dependent, so that in $3\operatorname{Res}(f(x))$ you see less space to the right of $\operatorname{Res}$ without any manual editing. Moreover with \operatorname*{Res}_{z=\zeta}, when in a "displayed" rather than "inline" setting, you see $\displaystyle \operatorname*{Res}_{z=\zeta},$ with the subscript below the operator.

Comment: . . . . . and I edited this answer accordingly.

Comment: . . . and now I've fixed the typos in my first comment above, so if you reload then you can read it.

Comment: @Jack Makes sense (given that the integral is not absolutely convergent).

Comment: @MichaelHardy: thanks for the improvement and the tips.